# Python fails to match a predefined string with a string entered from keyboard for same values.Is there some buffer logic that i'm missing here?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
choice = 'yes'
while choice is 'yes':
    choice = input("Enter a value for choice : ")
    # when i input 'yes' from keyboard for choice, it falls to else block.
    if choice is 'yes':
        print("As expected")
        break
    else:
        print("Need Help !!!")
```

I have even tried to match with 'yes\r', as we press 'enter' after our input from keyboard, it still failed to match. Need some insight.

Comment: `choice is 'yes'` does not do what you think it does... except just often enough to fool you into thinking it does what it doesn't do.

Comment: Use `==`, not `is`.  `is` compares the reference, not the value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `is` keyword is a test for object identity while == is a value comparison. Thus, you needed to change your `is` to `==`.

```
choice = 'yes'
while choice == 'yes':
    choice = input("Enter a value for choice : ")
    if choice == 'yes':
        print("As expected")
        break
    else:
        print("Need Help !!!")
```